# Return matching elements after comparing in lower case?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, underscore.js, lodash

I have this array:

`var mainArray = ["Title", "AssignedTo", "IssueStatus", "Priority", "Comment", "Category", "RelatedIssues", "V3Comments", "TaskDueDate", "Attachments"]`

I need to find these elements by comparing them with a lowercase equivalent

`var fields = ["title", "comment"];`

Basically, I need to find out if `fields` are included in `mainArray` and return the capitalized value from that array: `["Title", "Comment"]`

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: is `fields` an array with one string?

Comment: Sorry that's a spelling error

Comment: `mainArray.filter(x => fields.includes(x.toLowerCase()));`

Comment: At least show what you tried...problem isn't that complicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could filter the value after a check, if the lower case value is included in the `fields` array.

```js
var mainArray = ["Title", "AssignedTo", "IssueStatus", "Priority", "Comment", "Category", "RelatedIssues", "V3Comments", "TaskDueDate", "Attachments"],
    fields = ["title", "comment"],
    result = mainArray.filter(a => fields.includes(a.toLowerCase()));

console.log(result);
```

ES5

```js
var mainArray = ["Title", "AssignedTo", "IssueStatus", "Priority", "Comment", "Category", "RelatedIssues", "V3Comments", "TaskDueDate", "Attachments"],
    fields = ["title", "comment"],
    result = mainArray.filter(function (a) {
        return fields.indexOf(a.toLowerCase()) + 1;
    });

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var mainArray = ["Title", "AssignedTo", "IssueStatus", "Priority", "Comment", "Category", "RelatedIssues", "V3Comments", "TaskDueDate", "Attachments"]

var fields = ["title", "comment"];

var filtered = mainArray.filter(function(elem){
 return fields.indexOf(elem.toLowerCase()) != -1; 
});
```

Comment: Why the if statement at all? Just return the result of the condition. Also, you could use `includes` and an arrow function.

Comment: `includes`can be used, but it's not widely supported: 
[https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes?v=control](Array.prototype.includes())

Comment: It's supported on all major browsers except IE.

Comment: @AndrewLi you're right, but take a look at this: http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/esnext/#test-Array.prototype.includes

Comment: For old browsers, we need to use a polyfill.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this ES6 function which makes use of a map for better performance:

```js
function getMatches(a, b) {
    var mp = new Map(a.map( s => [s.toLowerCase(), s]));
    return b.map(mp.get, mp);
}

// Sample data and call
var mainArray = ["Title", "AssignedTo", "IssueStatus", "Priority", "Comment", "Category", "RelatedIssues", "V3Comments", "TaskDueDate", "Attachments"];
var fields = ["title", "comment"];
console.log(getMatches(mainArray, fields));
```

This will return just as many values as the second argument array, with `undefined` values where no match was found. If you do not want to know which entries failed, and only want those that did match, add a filter:

```
    return b.map(mp.get, mp).filter(s => s);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array#filter` method. See below.

```js
var mainArray = ["Title", "AssignedTo", "IssueStatus", "Priority", "Comment", "Category", "RelatedIssues", "V3Comments", "TaskDueDate", "Attachments"];


var fields = ["title", "comment"];

var res = mainArray.filter(function(v, i) {
     return fields.includes(v.toLowerCase());
});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score -1):

Just run array with for() and collect the result in outside variable with what you want, like this:

```
    var need = [];
    for(var i in yourArray){
    if(){ // compare function
    // add to "Need" array
    }
    }
// print the result
```

Also, you can wrap it into the function.
If you have a large array better to use a filter. But if you have a huge array better use ajax and the backend script.